# How to change google plus profile picture using google api Javascript SDK

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to build a Google+ App which uploads profile picture Using API JavaScript SDK. Is there any way to upload Google+ profile picture?

Comment: It's not possible yet.

Comment: Tum se na ho paye ga..

Answer (score 1):

There is no Google+ api that is available to developers. If you are working within your own domain you can do this with the Google Directory Api.

```
var newPhoto = AdminDirectory.newUserPhoto().photoData = (Utilities.base64Encode(photoBlob));

AdminDirectory.Users.Photos.update(newPhoto, "user@myDomain.org");
```